# Designing Date-Time schema in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, schema-design

I have a question on 'schema' design. To simplify, there are basically 2 entities, Universities and Students.  Students can be 'Current' or 'Past'.  Each Student has a 'start date' and, possibly, an 'end date'. Now, I can have a relationship from University to Student of type 'Current' or 'Past'. Students can be Current/Past in multiple Universities.

My question is - How do I represent the dates?

I can have the Date as a Property of the relationship (Past or Current), but that will not make it easy to answer, say, "Show me all students who started in 2009". Normally, I would have a separate date graph but since we don't have hyper edges in Neo4j, I'm not sure what the best design/practice would be…
I could create an intermediate node (e.g. 'CurrentStudent') that sits between each relationship, and connect that to the date graph (a fake hyperedge).  Any other thoughts?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

I'd put a `from` and `to` property onto a `studies_at` relationship from student to university. The value for `from` and `to` are the milliseconds since epoch (aka `Date.getTime()` in Java). A current student is indicated by `from` equals Long.MAX_VALUE.

Universities and students get a label and a indexed property for their name.

To find all students of a university starting in 2009:

```
MATCH (:University {name:'my university'})<-[r:STUDIES_AT}-(student:Student)
WHERE r.from >= {ms_since_epoch_for_Jan 1st 2009} 
  AND r.from <= {ms.since_epoch_for_Dec_31st 2009}
RETURN student
```

Of course you can introduce a time tree. Then the `studies_at` relationship becomes a node since the fact of studying is now a thing on it's own in your model. The studies_in node is connected to the student, the unversity and twice to the time tree, with a `starts` and `ends` relationship.

The time tree needs to have the granularity (day, minutes, seconds) mandated by the granularity of your searches.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan - that definitely makes sense.  I will model this by making the relationship as a node.  This will, indeed, give me additional flexibility.